# Tufte LaTeX not recognizing subequations and \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

Tags: tufte, subequations

I have a LaTeX document that I want to put in `tufte` format. However, when I compile it is not reconizing the `\begin{subequations}` (I used `\usepackage` and not accepting the `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` that I used so my matrices have columns painted gray.
Does anyone knows why this is happening?

A minimal working example where I show the packages I used and the type of things I want to do:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{units}

%Packages I included
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bbm}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
 \begin{array}{cc}
      \cellcolor{gray!25} 2 & \cellcolor{gray!25} 3 \\
      1 & 4
    \end{array}
    \right)}_{A}   
         \left(
    \begin{array}{c}
      \cellcolor{gray!25} v_{1}  \\
       \cellcolor{gray!25} v_{2}
    \end{array}
    \end{align*}

 $A^{-1}$ is a matrix such that: 
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
A \cdot A^{-1}&=A^{-1} \cdot A=I\,, \\
\left(A^{-1} \right) ^{-1}&=A\,, \\
\left( A^{t} \right) ^{-1}&=\left( A^{-1} \right)^{t}\,, \\
\left( A \cdot B \right)^{-1}&=B^{-1} \cdot A^{-1}\,.
\end{align}
\end{subequations}    
\end{document}
```

Some of the errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.
! LaTeX Error: Environment subequations undefined.
```

I use TexMaker and TeX Live 2012 (Mac OS 10.7.5)
Thank you!

Comment: Also it is not recognizing \begin{align}!
! LaTeX Error: Environment align undefined.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: the `subequations` environment is defined in `amsmath`, not in any of the other packages you have listed here.  are these *all* the packages you are using, and what is your document class.  the `align` environment is also defined in `amsmath`.  (welcome to tex.sx.)

Answer (score 4):

Let's handle each error one at a time:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.
```

This error occurs because the `tufte-book` document class is loading the `xcolor` package but isn't providing the `table` option.  To get around this issue, add this line *before* the `\documentclass` line:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}% must be *before* \documentclass
\documentclass{tufte-book}
```

Now:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment subequations undefined.
```

This error is because the `amsmath` package hasn't been loaded. Add `\usepackage{amsmath}` and this error should go away.